# Update value within a unix flat file

Tags: unix, csv, awk, sed

Kindly help. I want to make **.0** to be **0.0** within a UNIX file yyyyy.csv :

```
603905209;47.824;USD 
603905477;57.199;USD
603938657;3.2281;USD 
603949388;.00191;USD
603937274;.00563;USD
603911160;.00287;USD
```

I want the result to be

```
603905209;47.824;USD
603905477;57.199;USD
603938657;3.2281;USD
603949388;0.00191;USD
603937274;0.00563;USD
603911160;0.00287;USD
```

but I got this result:

```
603905209;0.4.7824;USD
603905477;0.5.7199;USD
603938657;0.3.2281;USD
603949388;0.00191;USD
603937274;0.00563;USD
603911160;0.00287;USD
```

Below is my command:

```
sed 's/;.0/;0.0/g' yyyyy.csv | sed 's/;.2/;0.2/g' | sed 's/;.1/;0.1/g' | sed 's/;.3/;0.3/g' | sed 's/;.4/;0.4/g' | sed 's/;.5/;0.5/g'| sed 's/;.6/;0.6/g' | sed 's/;.7/;0.7/g' | sed 's/;.8/;0.8/g' | sed 's/;.9/;0.9/g' > xxxxx.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape all the dots present in your regex or otherwise it would match any character. That is, `.` is a special meta character in regex which matches any character. To match a literal dot, you need to escape the `.`.

```
sed 's/;\.0/;0.0/g' yyyyy.csv
```

And this would be enough.

```
$ sed 's/;\.\([0-9]\)/;0.\1/g' file
603905477;57.199;USD
603938657;3.2281;USD 
603949388;0.00191;USD
603937274;0.00563;USD
603911160;0.00287;USD
```

In basic sed, `\(...\)` called [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html), which is used to capture the characters matched by the pattern present inside that group. So the pattern present inside the group is `[0-9]` which matches a digit from 0-9. We could refer the captured characters through  back-referencing ie, `\1`. `\1` at the replacement part refers to the characters which are present inside the group index 1.

Comment: @Raj. `$ sed 's/;\.\([0-9]\)/;0.\1/g' file`  This works well too. Can you explain me why the  \  after  `[0-9]`  and  `\1` . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change your command to:

```
sed 's/;\./;0./g' File
```

i.e, just substitute `;.` with `;0.`.

Answer (score 0):

Just print your file using a tool that understands numbers:

```
$ awk -F';' '{printf "%d;%f;%s\n", $1,$2,$3}' file   
603905209;47.824000;USD 
603905477;57.199000;USD
603938657;3.228100;USD 
603949388;0.001910;USD
603937274;0.005630;USD
603911160;0.002870;USD

awk -F';' '{printf "%d;%.5f;%s\n", $1,$2,$3}' file
603905209;47.82400;USD 
603905477;57.19900;USD
603938657;3.22810;USD 
603949388;0.00191;USD
603937274;0.00563;USD
603911160;0.00287;USD

$ awk -F';' '{printf "%d;%.2f;%s\n", $1,$2,$3}' file
603905209;47.82;USD 
603905477;57.20;USD
603938657;3.23;USD 
603949388;0.00;USD
603937274;0.01;USD
603911160;0.00;USD
```

Whatever precision you like...